# Per-cell standardization efficiently in NumPy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm standardizing each cell in my train/test matrices across all users (1st dimension) using the following code. This is of course highly inefficient, but I wanted to make sure the idea worked. How do I do it using NumPy's optimized methods?

```
   X_dims      = X.shape   
   channels    = 14 # not all columns as binary variables should stay untouched
   mu_cell     = np.zeros(shape=(channels, X_dims[2], X_dims[3]))
   sigma_cell  = np.zeros(shape=(channels, X_dims[2], X_dims[3]))

   for j in range(channels):
      for k in range(X_dims[2]):
         for l in range(X_dims[3]):
            mu_cell[j,k,l]    = np.mean(X_train[:,j,k,l])
            sigma_cell[j,k,l] = np.std(X_train[:,j,k,l])


   def standardizeCellWise(matrix):
      for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
         for j in range(channels):
            for k in range(matrix.shape[2]):
               for l in range(matrix.shape[3]):
                  matrix[i, j, k, l] -= mu_cell[j,k,l]
                  matrix[i, j, k, l] = matrix[i, j, k, l] / sigma_cell[j,k,l] if sigma_cell[j,k,l] != 0 else 0      
      return matrix

   X_train = standardizeCellWise(X_train)
   X_test  = standardizeCellWise(X_test)
```

Comment: can't you do `mu_cell = np.mean(X_train, axis=0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mu` and `sigma` arrays can be calculated in a *numpythonic* way as shown here -

```
import numpy as np

mu_cell = X_train[:,0:channels,:,:].mean(0)
sigma_cell = X_train[:,0:channels,:,:].std(0)
```

Next up, if you know that you don't have any infinite number or `NaN` in the input `matrix`, you can use this vectorized approach to standardize cells -

```
def standardizeCellWise(matrix,mu_cell,sigma_cell):
    matrix_cut = matrix[:,0:channels,:,:]
    matrix_cut = (matrix_cut - mu_cell[None,:])/sigma_cell[None,:]
    mask = ~np.isfinite(matrix_cut)
    matrix_cut[mask] = 0
    matrix[:,0:channels,:,:] = matrix_cut
    return matrix
```

For a general input matrix case, you just need to change the calculation of the `mask` like so -

```
mask = np.tile(sigma_cell[None,:]==0,[matrix.shape[0],1,1,1])
```